# Macro equivalence with nested macros in C

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

The following is taken from pngconf.h of libpng:
libpng version 1.6.3 - July 18, 2013
Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Glenn Randers-Pehrson

My question is, give the following macro preprocessors:

```
#ifndef PNG_FUNCTION 
#define PNG_FUNCTION(type, name, args, attributes) attributes type name args
#endif

#ifndef PNG_EXPORTA

#define PNG_EXPORTA(ordinal, type, name, args, attributes)\
   PNG_FUNCTION(PNG_EXPORT_TYPE(type),(PNGAPI name),PNGARG(args), \
    extern attributes)
#endif

#ifndef PNG_EXPORT_TYPE
#define PNG_EXPORT_TYPE(type) PNG_IMPEXP type
#endif

#ifndef PNGAPI
#define PNGAPI PNGCAPI
#endif

#define PNGCAPI __cdecl

#ifndef PNGARG
#define PNGARG(arglist) arglist
#endif
```

are the following equivalent?

```
#ifndef PNG_EXPORTA

#define PNG_EXPORTA(ordinal, type, name, args, attributes)\
  PNG_FUNCTION(PNG_EXPORT_TYPE(type),(PNGAPI name),PNGARG(args), \
    extern attributes)
#endif
```

is equivalent to:

```
#ifndef PNG_EXPORTA
#define PNG_EXPORTA(ordinal, type, name, args, attributes)\
extern attributes PNG_EXPORT_TYPE(type) (PNGCAPI name) PNGARG(args) 
#endif
```

which is finally equivalent to:

```
#ifndef PNG_EXPORTA

#define PNG_EXPORTA(ordinal, type, name, args, attributes)\
extern attributes PNG_IMPEXP type __cdecl name arglist 
#endif
```

Comment: Most compilers allow you to see the preprocessor output.  For example, run GCC with the `-E` flag.

Comment: On first glance, I would say the answer to the question of equivalence is "no". I think you inserted some commas where they didn't exist when you translated the `PNG_FUNCTION` macro. And welcome to the SO code parsing service. ;)

Comment: Seconding the comment by @mbratch: you have `extern attributes,` where you should have just `extern attributes`.

Comment: Thank you all. Don't know if there is anything else.

Comment: VS2012 dev cmd: `cl /EP /C /P pngconf.h`

Answer (score 1):

@OliverCharlesworth wrote:

> Most compilers allow you to see the preprocessor output. For example, run GCC with the `-E` flag.

@lurker wrote:

> On first glance, I would say the answer to the question of equivalence is "no". I think you inserted some commas where they didn't exist when you translated the PNG_FUNCTION macro. And welcome to the SO code parsing service. ;)

@JonathanLeffler wrote:

> you have `extern attributes,` where you should have just `extern attributes`.

Comment: ([Answered in the comments and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments))